# WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 no output for Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

#### Issue

I'm on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04, trying to run a Docker container in "interactive tty" mode, and I simply can't see the output of the container in the terminal.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. WSL2 terminal - Run a container and execute a command

   ```sh
   $ docker run --rm -it alpine:3.12

   # in container
   $ ls 
   # hit enter, can't see anything
   ```
2. WSL terminal - Scroll up and then down, suddenly the output appears

I was able to overcome it with [ttyd](https://github.com/tsl0922/ttyd), but I prefer using my terminal, any leads on this one?

#### Things that I've tried

1. Ubuntu 20.04 is my default distribution

   ```
   PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --list --verbose
     NAME                   STATE           VERSION
   * Ubuntu-20.04           Running         2
     docker-desktop-data    Running         2
     docker-desktop         Running         2
   ```
2. Docker for Desktop > Settings > Resources > WSL Integration > Checked both `Enable integration with my default WSL distro` and `Ubuntu-20.04`. I also unchecked, Applied & Restarted > Same results
3. [Troubleshooting Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting)
    > [OpenSSH-Server connection issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting)
4. PowerShell as Administrator > `wsl --shutdown` > Same results
5. I can see the output of a container that prints something

   ```sh
   $ docker run -it --rm unfor19/catfact:1.0 sh
   Cat fact:
   The first cartoon cat was Felix the Cat in 1919.
   In 1940, Tom and Jerry starred in the first theatrical cartoon “Puss Gets the Boot.”
   In 1981 Andrew Lloyd Weber created the musical Cats, based on T.S. Eliot’s Old Possum’s Book of Practical Cats
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's related to the fact my `$PATH` variable was changed in my `~/.bashrc` file.

I was able to fix it by following the instructions in

- [Troubleshooting Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting) > [Running Windows commands fails inside a distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#running-windows-commands-fails-inside-a-distribution)

Adding the following line to my `~/.bashrc` followed by `wsl --shutdown` fixed it

```sh
# Support Windows commands
export PATH="${PATH}:/mnt/c/Windows/system32"
```